# Add Custom menu items to TimeLine using Mirror API .Net client

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

How I insert Custom menu items using Mirror API .NET client.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/mirror/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Mirror_1_1v1_1_1Data_1_1TimelineItem.html#ac95fb985d873aed1ed8277c8bfcd3374 for more about adding menu items to a Timeline object. The MenuItem object Action is described at https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/mirror/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Mirror_1_1v1_1_1Data_1_1MenuItem.html#a4b3f412526fe4a4cd68a760a0ef95d0c and https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/mirror/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Mirror_1_1v1_1_1Data_1_1MenuItem.html#ac499b1aaa93ce833a6d9eb20eaba43fe for how to set what values will be shown for that menu item.

General guidance on Timeline items and adding custom menu items are available at https://developers.google.com/glass/menu-items#defining_custom_menu_items.

Finally, there is example source at https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-dotnet/blob/master/Controllers/MainController.cs that shows how to Insert an item with an action, and you should be able to adapt the MenuItem there to use a custom menu.